# Force props to update in child component after Vuex update

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-props

I have a child component (`<BaseProjectTable>`) that is re-used throughout my site that contains a Vuetify `<v-data-table>` component. The headers and content items for the data table are passed into the the component as props, and the item data is mapped into the parent as a `mapGetter` from a Vuex store. The child component contains editing functionality for each row, and I'm using a `mapAction` to update the API and Vuex data from there, with the idea being that since my mapGetter is reactive, it should update the data and hence the data table display. However, this is not working; I can see via dev tools that state is updated just fine, but the child component display is not.

Here is the relevant portion of the child `<BaseProjectTable>` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      show-expand
      :headers="headers"
      :items="filteredItems"
      :search="search"
      tem-key="sow"
      @click:row="rowClick"
      :hide-default-footer="disablePagination"
      dense
      :disable-pagination="disablePagination"
    >
    ...
    </v-data-table>

    ...
    export default {
    name: "BaseProjectTable",
    props: {
      headers: Array,
      items: Array,
      loggedInUser: Object,
      title: String,
      max2chars: v => v.length <= 2 || 'Input too long!',
      editDialog: false,
      showPracticeFilter: {
        default: true,
        type: Boolean
      },
      showSEFilter: {
        default: true,
        type: Boolean
      },
      showStatusFilter: {
        default: true,
        type: Boolean
      },
      projectType: {
        type: String,
        default: 'active'
      },
      disablePagination: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
  ...mapActions('projects', {
        saveProject: 'saveProject',
    }), 
    save() {
      // Update API and store with new data.
      this.saveProject({
        projectType: this.projectType,
        projectData: this.editedItem
      })
  },
  computed: {
      statuses()  {
        return this.projectType === 'active' ? this.activeStatuses : this.oppStatuses;
      },
      filteredItems() {
        return this.items.filter(d => {
          return Object.keys(this.filters).every(f => {
            return this.filters[f].length < 1 || this.filters[f].includes(d[f])
          })
        })
      },
    }
```

and here is the relevant code from the parent component:

```
<v-card>
  <BaseProjectTable
    :headers="headers"
    :items="activeProjects"
    :loggedInUser="loggedInUser"
    title="Active Projects"
    :disablePagination=false
  ></BaseProjectTable>
</v-card>
...
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('projects', {
      activeProjects: 'activeProjects',
      closedProjects: 'closedProjects',
      opportunities: 'opportunities'
    }),
  }
}
```

The `save()` method updates the data in my Vuex store that is referenced by the `activeProjects` map getter (I have verified in the Vue devtools that this is true). It also shows the `items` value in the component itself updated in the `Components` tab in the dev tools. Since using `mapGetters` makes the data reactive, I expected that it would also update the data in my child component, but it doesn't.

Based on what I saw [here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render), I tried the `item-key` property of the <`v-data-table>` like so:

```
<v-data-table
  show-expand
  :headers="headers"
  :items="filteredItems"
  :search="search"
  item-key="sow"
  @click:row="rowClick"
  :hide-default-footer="disablePagination"
  dense
  :disable-pagination="disablePagination"
>
```

(every record using this component will have the unique `sow` key), but that didn't work.

The only think I could think if is how I'm editing the data in my mutation:

```
export const state = () => ({
    active: [],
    closed: [],
    opportunities: [],
})

export const getters = {
  activeProjects: state => state.active,
  closedProjects: state => state.closed,
  opportunities: state => state.opportunities,
}

export const actions = {
  saveProject({ commit }, {projectType, projectData}) {
    commit(types.SAVE_PROJECT, {projectType, projectData});
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  [types.SAVE_PROJECT](state, {projectType, projectData}) {
    // Get project from state list by sow field.
    const index = state[projectType].findIndex(p => p.sow === projectData.sow);
    state[projectType][index] = projectData;
  }
}
```

as compared to replacing the entire `state[projectType]` value.

What do I need to do to get the data table to display my updated value?

Comment: Is `active` in store the same as `activeProjects`? Could not correlate the mutation - I may have missed something there. Did you try replacing `state[projectType][index] = projectData;` with `this.$set(state[projectType], index, projectData)` - that should ensure reactivity and reflect changes in getter.

Comment: Yes, it is (I added the getters to the code above). My problem is that I can see my changes in the getter in the Vue devtools - they're just not being reflected in the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html),

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array

> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
> - When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

Replace what you have with

```js
import Vue from 'vue'; // this should be at the top level

export const mutations = {
  [types.SAVE_PROJECT](state, {projectType, projectData}) {
    // Get project from state list by sow field.
    const index = state[projectType].findIndex(p => p.sow === projectData.sow);
    Vue.set(state[projectType], index, projectData)
  }
}
```

After this, the changes to the array will be detected and the getter will work as expected.

Comment: Hmmm, that seems weird having to use `Vue.set()` inside of a mutation, but it works.

Comment: The Vuex [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules) confirms that it's appropriate to use `Vue.set` inside a mutation.

Comment: If you don't mind, please accept the answer for the benefit of anyone who stumbles upon this page @wonder95